# Fancybox issue, need a hand

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox, gallery

I made a gallery with images fetched from DB and using `Fancybox` for displaying it. I have some articles that are the same, just diferent color and I display just one and underneath color boxes for changing the color.

> **The problem is that when I click on the button to change the color, picture changes, Fancybox on click displays first picture, not the Current one**

Part of the code:

JS:

```
function changeImage(element,id){
    var img=document.getElementById(id).src=element;
    return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $prikaz =$row['prikaz'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $ime = $row['ime'];
    $thumb = $row['thumbs'];
    $boja = $row['boja_id'];
    $slicka = $row['slika'];
    $spec = $row['tekst'];

    if ($prikaz == 1){

        echo "<table style ='display: inline' align='center'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a class='fancybox-effects-a' href='$slicka' ><img id='$id' src='$thumb' alt='' /></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "Boja: ";
        $bsql = mysql_query ("SELECT muski.tekst, muski.id,muski.thumbs,boja.bslika FROM boja INNER JOIN muski ON muski.boja_id = boja.id WHERE muski.ime = '$ime' " );                  

        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($bsql)){ 

            $slicica = $res['thumbs'];    
            $muid = $res['id'];
            $kockica = $res['bslika'];
            echo "<button id = 'boja' onclick =changeImage('$slicica','$id')><img src= $kockica ></button>";

        }

        echo "</br>";
        echo nl2br($spec);

}

echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";    
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: well, you are changing the thumb `src` in the `changeImage()` function but not the `href` of the parent anchor. You may need to tweak your function to change both (may need some more parameters to pass though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.... I modified js script to change the parent `href` of img... It works...

```
function changeImage(element,id,staza) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
        img.src= element;
        img.parentNode.href=staza;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firebug your Fancy Box pop-up and inside the you have to change back ground image as well

Comment: translation please : what `background image`?

Comment: when you click on any image and it opens inside fancybox popup at that time basically you set background-image of that pop up as well .click on image then it will open in fancybox then firebug that fancybox go to inner divs and somewhere you will find background image

Comment: sorry but that is not the way it works. it doesn't use background images but `<img />` tags if you know what I mean.